# What is the Java equivalent of a Scala object?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In Scala, we can write

```
object Foo { def bar = {} }
```

How is this implemented by the compiler? I am able to call `Foo.bar();` from Java
but `new Foo();` from Java gives the error `cannot find symbol symbol: constructor Foo()`

- Does the JVM support singletons natively?
- Is it possible to have a class in Java that does not have a constructor?

Note: here is the code output by `scalac -print`

```
package <empty> {
  final class Foo extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def bar(): Unit = ();
    def this(): object Foo = {
      Foo.super.this();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Support for singletons** is not on a language level, but the language provides enough facilities to create them without any trouble.

Consider the following code:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This is an example from Wikipedia, which explains how a singleton can be made. An instance is kept in a private field, constructor is inaccessible outside the class, the method returns this single instance.

**As for constructors:** every class by default has a so-called *default constructor* which takes no arguments and simply calls the no-args constructor of the superclass. If the superclass doesn't have any accessible constructor without arguments, you will have to write an explicit constructor.

So a class must have a constructor, but you don't have to write it if the superclass has a no-args constructor.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/?ref=lbp talks about ```ensure only 1 instance``` of the ```Singleton``` is created.

Answer (score 23):

When compiling your code, Scala compiler produces an equivalent of the following Java code:

```
public final class Foo {
    private Foo() {} // Actually, Foo doesn't have constructor at all
                     // It can be represented in bytecode, 
                     // but it cannot be represented in Java language

    public static final void bar() {
        Foo$.MODULE$.bar();
    }
}

public final class Foo$ implements ScalaObject {
    public static final Foo$ MODULE$;
    static {
        new Foo$();
    }
    private Foo$() { MODULE$ = this; }
    public final void bar() {
        // actual implementation of bar()
    }
}
```

Here `Foo$` is an actual implementation of a singleton, whereas `Foo` provides a `static` method for interaction with Java.

Comment: Is there any way to see the "intermediate" Java code, as you have shown? Did you use a decompiler to generate it?

Comment: @Jus12: Perhaps some decompilers are able to show it, but I reconstructed it manually from the output of `javap -c -private Foo` / `javap -c -private Foo$`

Comment: Hi @axtavt, what is this part called?  ```static {
        new Foo$();
    }```   other members(methods fields) all have a name. what type of member is this?

Answer (score 4):

Joshua Bloch recommened in the book "Effective Java" the use of an enum to implement a singleton.

See this question:
[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java)