# Autowired not working in Scala Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

Taking into account the following example where I'm trying to use the `Sample` configuration bean within `SampleStarter` to start the service with the bean properly filled. The .scala file has `SampleStarter.scala` as name, with `Sample` being defined within that exact same file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Service
object SampleStarter {

  @(Autowired @setter)
  var sample: Sample = _ // always null, @Autowired not working?

  def getInstance() = this

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Sample], args: _*)

    sample.run()
  }

}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("sample")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class Sample {

  @BeanProperty
  var myProperty: String = _

  def run(): Unit = { // bean config seems OK, when debugging with @PostConstruct the 'myProperty' value is filled properly
    print(myProperty)
  }

}
```

Whenever I hit `sample.run()` after `SpringApplication.run(classOf[Sample], args: _*)`, `sample` property is always null. I reckon this has something to do with `object` in Scala since all their members are static AFAIK. I took this SO question [How to use Spring Autowired (or manually wired) in Scala object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344224/how-to-use-spring-autowired-or-manually-wired-in-scala-object) as inspiration but still can't make my code to work.

Is there something wrong the way I'm instantiating the classes or is it something related to Scala?

**EDIT**

Following @Rob's answer, this is what I did trying to replicate his solution.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Service
object SampleStarter {

  @(Autowired @setter)
  var sample: Sample = _

  def getInstance() = this

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Sample], args: _*)

    sample.run()
  }

}


@Configuration // declares this class a source of beans
@ConfigurationProperties("sample") // picks up from various config locations
@EnableConfigurationProperties // not certain this is necessary
class AppConfiguration {

  @BeanProperty
  var myProperty: String = _

  @Bean
  // Error -> Parameter 0 of constructor in myproject.impl.Sample required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
  def sample: Sample = new Sample(myProperty)

}

class Sample(@BeanProperty var myProperty: String) {

  def run(): Unit = {
    print(myProperty)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Configuration` declares a source file that is capable of providing `@Bean`s.  This is not what you want. You want/need to have Sample as a POJO class (POSO?) and then have another class "AppConfiguration" (say) annotated with `@Configuration` that creates an `@Bean` of type `Sample`

My scala is very rusty so this may not compile at all but the structure should be roughly correct.

```scala
@Configuration // declares this class a source of beans
@ConfigurationProperties("sample") // picks up from various config locations
@EnableConfigurationProperties // not certain this is necessary
class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  def getSample(@BeanProperty myProperty: String): Sample = new Sample(myProperty)

}
```

```scala
class Sample {

  var myProperty: String

  def Sample(property : String) = {
    this.myProperty = myProperty
  }

  def run(): Unit = {
    print(myProperty)
  }
}
```

Now you have a `Sample` class as an `@Bean` and it can be `@Autowired` in where ever necessary.

```scala
@SpringBootApplication
@Service
object SampleStarter {

  // note its typically better to inject variables into a constructor
  // rather than directly into fields as the behaviour is more predictable
  @Autowired
  var sample: Sample

  def getInstance() = this // not required ??

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Sample], args: _*)

    sample.run()
  }
}
```

FWIW, you can start the SpringBoot application independently and have the logic for `@Service` entirely separate. An `@Service` is another type of `@Bean` and is made available to the rest of the SpringBootApplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying Rob! Got my doubts crystal clear with the @Configuration and @Service!

However, I'm struggling to load the bean since it will complain with "Parameter 0 of constructor in myproject.impl.Sample required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found."

Will update the first post with some modifications I did trying to make it work.