# in Scala, i need to invoke a Java method in the custom component present in spring org.springframework.stereotype

Tags: java, spring, scala

In Scala, how to invoke the application context to consume a custom jar library written using org.springframework.stereotype @Component annotation .

The @Component is used to create the java class files, i need to invoke there associated methods in the scala.

Any inputs is appreciated.

Spring custom library -> Has @component with a method.

Need to inject the bean and invoke its associated method in scala.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Spring Autowired (or manually wired) in Scala object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344224/how-to-use-spring-autowired-or-manually-wired-in-scala-object)

Comment: no,I have a java @\component, that has many @\Injected Bean / Components, so need to call the top level @\Component by creating a object and access it method in Scala. The @\component is java spring belongs to package org.springframework.stereotype.Component. How to handle @\component objects / auto wire in Scala ?!

Comment: could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?