# Accessing a Scala object from Java code

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to use a Scala class that has a default argument:

```
object SimpleCredStashClient {

  def apply(kms: AWSKMSClient, dynamo: AmazonDynamoDBClient, aes: AESEncryption = DefaultAESEncryption) 
  ...
}
```

When I try to instantiate an instance of this class from Java, I get the error:

```
Error:(489, 43) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method SimpleCredStashClient(com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient,com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient)
  location: class com.engineersgate.build.util.CredentialsUtil
```

`DefaultAESEncryption` is a Scala object. How do I access the Scala object in Java?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819866/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-a-scala-object

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments become synthetic methods of the form `<meth>$default$<idx>()`. Further, instances of an object `A` may be found at `A$.MODULE$` (if `A` is a top-level `object`), or at `outer.A()` (if `A` is defined as something like `class O { object A }`).Therefore, there are two ways to do this:

Direct usage of object:

```java
SimpleCredStashClient.apply(
    kms,
    dynamo,
    DefaultAESEncryption$.MODULE$
);
```

Default argument:

```java
SimpleCredStashClient.apply(
    kms,
    dynamo,
    SimpleCredStashClient.apply$default$3()
);
```

The first one certainly looks better, but if the default argument ever changes, you'll have to update this code too. In the second one, the argument is whatever the default argument is, and will only break if the argument stops having a default, or changes its index. Scala uses the second method when compiled.

Comment: Since the SimpleCredStashClient is also an object, should we use `SimpleCredStashClient.apply` or `SimpleCredStashClient$.apply`?

Comment: `SimpleCredStashClient.apply` is a `static` method generated by `scalac` for the sole purpose of Java interop, so you should use that. It simply forwards to `SimpleCredStashClient$.MODULE$.apply`, which is what Scala code ends up using.